# How to check is Apache2 is stopped in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, process, apache2

I want to make sure apache2 service is stopped.

```
1. I need to verify if apache2 is installed or not.
```

when I type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

I got:

```
sudo: /etc/init.d/apache2: command not found
```

Does this mean apache2 is not installed? Or is it installed in another place?

```
2. check apache2 process:
```

when I type:

```
ps a | grep apache2
```

I got:

```
10448 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto apache2
```

Does it mean apache2 is running?

```
3. http://localhost test
```

I got:

```
Google Chrome could not connect to localhost
```

How can I verify that Apache2 is stopped?

Comment: you have to actually give apache a command....

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In the command line type `service apache2 status` then hit enter. The result should say:

> Apache2 is running (pid xxxx)

Comment: output:   apache2: unrecognized service. Does this mean apache2 has not been installed?

Comment: Yes its not installed if its not under services. try "sudo apt-get install apache2" to install it

Comment: for scripting: `test $(service apache2 status &> /dev/null; echo "$?") -gt "0" && echo "not running"`

Answer (score 4):

You can also type "top" and look at the list of running processes.

Comment: hit q to quite this after